# Unity WP8 sample not working

Tags: windows-phone-8, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am trying to develop a unity plugin for WP8. I followed the following guide: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/wp8-plugins-guide-csharp.html

Then copied the fake dll to assets/plugin and real dll to assets/plugin/WP8.
I created the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AdDemo : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        string t = UnityPluginForWindowsPhone.Class1.GetDeviceName;
    }   
}
```

When compiling in Unity 4.5 I get the following error:

Internal compiler error. See the console log for more information. output was:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.RootNamespace.ComputeNamespace (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx, System.Type extensionType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.GlobalRootNamespace.ComputeNamespaces (Mono.CSharp.CompilerContext ctx) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.LoadReferences () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Compile () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Did anybody get this to work?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @user1351643 if you get solution then please let me know i am getting same problem here.

Comment: I found one solution that is change .net framework 3.5 but i did not found how to change .net framework in Visual Studio for window phone

Comment: Finally i found solution after struggling 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found solution after struggling 2 days. The solution in the tutorials it self.
You should use Plugins folder under Assets folder.
Here you missed `'s'` in Plugin folder `assets/plugin/WP8`
This should like this `Assets/Plugins/WP8`